# Push functions and get callback

Tags: javascript

I have a basic widget which i can push function calls to (almost like Google analytics, ga.js)

Here is the widget code:

```
var widget = function () {

    function _private_setName(a, callback) {
        console.log(a[0]);

        callback(a[0]);
    }

    return{
       setName:_private_setName
    };  
}();

if (window._test) {
    for (var i = 0; i < _test.length; i++) {
        var method = _test[i].shift();
        try {
            widget[method].apply(widget, _test);
        }
        catch(err) { }
    }
}

window._test = {
    push: function() {
        try {
            var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
            var method = args[0].shift();
            widget[method].apply(widget, args);
        }
        catch(err) { }  
    }
};
```

So what i can currently do is this:

```
var _test = _test || [];
_test.push(['setName', 'Todd']);
```

However i would like to be able to get callbacks from the function setName.

I've tried:

```
_test.push('setName', 'Todd', function(num) {
    console.log("callback called! " + num);
});
```

But i cannot get it to work, any ideas how i can implement this?

Comment: Have you tried not swallowing `err`? I reckon there's a bug in there

Comment: `TypeError: undefined is not a function` from `args[0].shift()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change

```
var method = args[0].shift();
```

to

```
var method = args.shift();
```

After that the callback will be called. Here is a jsfiddle with a working version http://jsfiddle.net/krasimir/pLuad/1/

Answer (score 0):

That's some pretty hanky janky code you've got there to achieve what you're looking to do. A common practice with callback is to use arguments[arguments.length -1], in the function you are passing the callback to, so it's always the "last" argument that will be used as the callback function. Then you say

```
if(typeof arguments[arguments.length - 1] === 'function'){
    arguments[arguments.length - 1](dataToPassToCallback);
}
```

In your situation, it seems like you are adding a lot of needless abstraction and making this much more difficult than it needs to be. For example, you are declaring a "widget" object/class, and then you are assigning static instances of itself to it ( widget[fnName] = widget.apply()) - so now when you are declaring more widgets, they are all containing references to the other widget methods.

I would imagine what you really want is for Widget class to be it's own thing and for there to be a WidgetManager class or a Widgets class that will then do similar things to what your _test array is doing.